# Progress Bar using nprogress.Js

Tags: javascript, css

i want to make a progress bar like youtube bar progress, im using the plugins nprogress.js, but i want to start the progress from the middle of page somthing like, youtube bar :

```
start | ---------------------------------------------> | end
```

that what i want :

```
start | emtpyemptyemtpyemtpyempty--------------------> | end
```

here is the nprogress website **http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/**

on github : **https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/**

how i can do that please, and thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

NProgress.set(0.4) — sets a percentage

If you want to go to the middle, set 0.5 o 50 or something... If this is not what you are looking for, please excuse me, i have a very bad english...
Also, if it has only four functions exposed, and none of them can do the work you want, i think that the only solution is adding it to Nprogress code :P

Comment: i dont want to go to the middle, i want to start from middle, how ?

Comment: You mean starting from the middle but without painting the bar before the middle point?
nprogress doesn't have a function for that (well, at least i didn't find anything about)... You can take a look at nprogress code and add it. There must be a part of the code that paints the bar... just add the code to start painting from a determinated point,,,

Comment: Thnx, i fix the prob, i create a **div** then i give it a margin-left, and into nprogress.js line 30 there's **parent: 'body'**, i change the **body** to my new **div** !

Comment: Glad to read that you solve the problem n.n

Don't forget to share the solution to help others :)

Comment: Yeah That for sure :)